# With PYTHON convert CSV file to XML file

Tags: python, xml, csv

I want convert a csv file to xml file with python. I want to group the same id's in the csv file together and convert the csv in to convert xml( see desired ouput ). Its a bit complex than it looks with indentation, looping and grouping the csv to xml. All help is appreciated.

```
My CSV file:

id,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,c1,R
a1,1.3,2.1,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.8,B,7.3
b2,1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,G,7.1
c1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,G,8.1
a1,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,S,8.2
b2,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,S,2.5
b2,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.3,7.4,8.2,G,3.1
c2,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,2.1,11.1,S,3.2
c1,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,A,1.5


my code:

import itertools
import csv
import os

csvFile = r'C:\Users\Desktop\test XML\csvfile.csv'
xmlFile = r'C:\Users\Desktop\test XML\myData.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + "\n" +'<Roughness-Profiles xmlns="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">' + "\n" )
xmlData.write(' '+'<Roughness-Profile>' + "\n")

rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
        xmlData.write('  '+'<surfaces>' +"\n"+'   '+'<surface>' + "\n")
        for i in range (len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('    ' +'<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                      + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

        xmlData.write('   '+'</surface>' + "\n" + '  '+'</surfaces>' + "\n" + ' '+'</Roughness-Profile>' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</Roughness-Profiles>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

my xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Roughness-Profiles xmlns="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">
 <Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>a1</id>
    <x1>1.3</x1>
    <y1>2.1</y1>
    <z1>3.6</z1>
    <x2>4.5</x2>
    <y2>5.1</y2>
    <z2>6.8</z2>
    <c1>B</c1>
    <R>7.3</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>b2</id>
    <x1>1.1</x1>
    <y1>2.1</y1>
    <z1>3.1</z1>
    <x2>4.1</x2>
    <y2>5.1</y2>
    <z2>6.1</z2>
    <c1>G</c1>
    <R>7.1</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>c1</id>
    <x1>2.1</x1>
    <y1>3.1</y1>
    <z1>4.1</z1>
    <x2>5.1</x2>
    <y2>2.1</y2>
    <z2>7.1</z2>
    <c1>G</c1>
    <R>8.1</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>a1</id>
    <x1>2.2</x1>
    <y1>3.2</y1>
    <z1>4.2</z1>
    <x2>5.2</x2>
    <y2>6.2</y2>
    <z2>7.2</z2>
    <c1>S</c1>
    <R>8.2</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>b2</id>
    <x1>4.1</x1>
    <y1>5.1</y1>
    <z1>2.1</z1>
    <x2>7.1</x2>
    <y2>8.1</y2>
    <z2>9.1</z2>
    <c1>S</c1>
    <R>2.5</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>b2</id>
    <x1>3.6</x1>
    <y1>4.5</y1>
    <z1>5.1</z1>
    <x2>6.3</x2>
    <y2>7.4</y2>
    <z2>8.2</z2>
    <c1>G</c1>
    <R>3.1</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>c2</id>
    <x1>6.1</x1>
    <y1>7.1</y1>
    <z1>8.1</z1>
    <x2>9.1</x2>
    <y2>2.1</y2>
    <z2>11.1</z2>
    <c1>S</c1>
    <R>3.2</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <id>c1</id>
    <x1>1.5</x1>
    <y1>1.5</y1>
    <z1>1.5</z1>
    <x2>1.5</x2>
    <y2>1.5</y2>
    <z2>1.5</z2>
    <c1>A</c1>
    <R>1.5</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </Roughness-Profile>
</Roughness-Profiles>
```

Desired output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<R-Profiles xmlns="http://WKI/R-Profiles/1">
 <R-Profile>
  <id>a1</id>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <x1>1.3</x1>
    <y1>2.1</y1>
    <z1>3.6</z1>
    <x2>4.5</x2>
    <y2>5.1</y2>
    <z2>6.8</z2>
    <c1>B</c1>
    <R>7.3</R>
   </surface>
   <surface>
    <x1>2.2</x1>
    <y1>3.2</y1>
    <z1>4.2</z1>
    <x2>5.2</x2>
    <y2>6.2</y2>
    <z2>7.2</z2>
    <c1>S</c1>
    <R>8.2</R>
   </surface>
    </surfaces>
 </R-Profile>
 <R-Profile>
  <id>b2</id>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <x1>1.1</x1>
    <y1>2.1</y1>
    <z1>3.1</z1>
    <x2>4.1</x2>
    <y2>5.1</y2>
    <z2>6.1</z2>
    <c1>G</c1>
    <R>7.1</R>
   </surface>
   <surface>
    <x1>4.1</x1>
    <y1>5.1</y1>
    <z1>2.1</z1>
    <x2>7.1</x2>
    <y2>8.1</y2>
    <z2>9.1</z2>
    <c1>S</c1>
    <R>2.5</R>
   </surface>
   <surface>
    <x1>3.6</x1>
    <y1>4.5</y1>
    <z1>5.1</z1>
    <x2>6.3</x2>
    <y2>7.4</y2>
    <z2>8.2</z2>
    <c1>G</c1>
    <R>3.1</R>
   </surface>
    </surfaces>
 </R-Profile>
 <R-Profile>
  <id>c1</id>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <x1>2.1</x1>
    <y1>3.1</y1>
    <z1>4.1</z1>
    <x2>5.1</x2>
    <y2>2.1</y2>
    <z2>7.1</z2>
    <c1>G</c1>
    <R>8.1</R>
   </surface>
   <surface>
    <x1>1.5</x1>
    <y1>1.5</y1>
    <z1>1.5</z1>
    <x2>1.5</x2>
    <y2>1.5</y2>
    <z2>1.5</z2>
    <c1>A</c1>
    <R>1.5</R>
   </surface>
   </surfaces>
 </R-Profile>
 <R-Profile>
  <id>c2</id>
  <surfaces>
   <surface>
    <x1>6.1</x1>
    <y1>7.1</y1>
    <z1>8.1</z1>
    <x2>9.1</x2>
    <y2>2.1</y2>
    <z2>11.1</z2>
    <c1>S</c1>
    <R>3.2</R>
   </surface>
  </surfaces>
 </R-Profile>
</R-Profiles>
```

Comment: first read all rows from `CSV` and sort them by `id`

Comment: thats not at all the issue. same ids need to group, see the xml structure in desired output

Comment: grouping is not problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something very similar to what @Parfait suggested; use [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) to create the XML.

However, something is missing from that answer; the `surface` elements aren't grouped by `id`.

If I need to group XML during a transformation, the first thing I think of is XSLT.

Once you get the hang of it, grouping is easy with XSLT; especially 2.0 or greater. Unfortunately lxml only supports XSLT 1.0. In 1.0 you need to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Here's a full example of creating an intermediate XML and transforming it with XSLT.

**CSV Input** (test.csv)

```
id,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,c1,R
a1,1.3,2.1,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.8,B,7.3
b2,1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,G,7.1
c1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,G,8.1
a1,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,S,8.2
b2,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,S,2.5
b2,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.3,7.4,8.2,G,3.1
c2,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,2.1,11.1,S,3.2
c1,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,A,1.5
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:rp="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="surface" match="rp:surface" use="rp:id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="rp:surface[count(.|key('surface',rp:id)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:element name="Roughness-Profile" namespace="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="rp:id"/>
          <xsl:element name="surfaces" namespace="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('surface',rp:id)"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rp:id"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```py
import csv
import lxml.etree as etree

# INITIALIZING XML FILE WITH ROOT IN PROPER NAMESPACE
nsmap = {None: "http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1"}
root = etree.Element('Roughness-Profiles', nsmap=nsmap)

# READING CSV FILE
with open("test.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    # WRITE INITIAL XML NODES
    for row in reader:
        surface_elem = etree.SubElement(root, "surface", nsmap=nsmap)
        for elem_name, elem_value in row.items():
            etree.SubElement(surface_elem, elem_name.strip(), nsmap=nsmap).text = str(elem_value)

# PARSE XSLT AND CREATE TRANSFORMER
xslt_root = etree.parse("test.xsl")
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)

# TRANSFORM
#  (Note the weird use of tostring/fromstring. This was used so
#   namespaces in the XSLT would work the way they're supposed to.)
final_xml = transform(etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(root)))

# WRITE OUTPUT TO FILE
final_xml.write_output("test.xml")
```

**XML Output** (test.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Roughness-Profiles xmlns="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">
  <Roughness-Profile>
    <id>a1</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>1.3</x1>
        <y1>2.1</y1>
        <z1>3.6</z1>
        <x2>4.5</x2>
        <y2>5.1</y2>
        <z2>6.8</z2>
        <c1>B</c1>
        <R>7.3</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>2.2</x1>
        <y1>3.2</y1>
        <z1>4.2</z1>
        <x2>5.2</x2>
        <y2>6.2</y2>
        <z2>7.2</z2>
        <c1>S</c1>
        <R>8.2</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </Roughness-Profile>
  <Roughness-Profile>
    <id>b2</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>1.1</x1>
        <y1>2.1</y1>
        <z1>3.1</z1>
        <x2>4.1</x2>
        <y2>5.1</y2>
        <z2>6.1</z2>
        <c1>G</c1>
        <R>7.1</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>4.1</x1>
        <y1>5.1</y1>
        <z1>2.1</z1>
        <x2>7.1</x2>
        <y2>8.1</y2>
        <z2>9.1</z2>
        <c1>S</c1>
        <R>2.5</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>3.6</x1>
        <y1>4.5</y1>
        <z1>5.1</z1>
        <x2>6.3</x2>
        <y2>7.4</y2>
        <z2>8.2</z2>
        <c1>G</c1>
        <R>3.1</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </Roughness-Profile>
  <Roughness-Profile>
    <id>c1</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>2.1</x1>
        <y1>3.1</y1>
        <z1>4.1</z1>
        <x2>5.1</x2>
        <y2>2.1</y2>
        <z2>7.1</z2>
        <c1>G</c1>
        <R>8.1</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>1.5</x1>
        <y1>1.5</y1>
        <z1>1.5</z1>
        <x2>1.5</x2>
        <y2>1.5</y2>
        <z2>1.5</z2>
        <c1>A</c1>
        <R>1.5</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </Roughness-Profile>
  <Roughness-Profile>
    <id>c2</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>6.1</x1>
        <y1>7.1</y1>
        <z1>8.1</z1>
        <x2>9.1</x2>
        <y2>2.1</y2>
        <z2>11.1</z2>
        <c1>S</c1>
        <R>3.2</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </Roughness-Profile>
</Roughness-Profiles>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, your advise works good. It works for this example file but if i run the script i get at ' line 16 ' , ValueError: Invalid tag name.You haveany idea How to get rid of his error?

Comment: @Ram - That means one of your header values can’t be used as-is for an element name. Can you tell me what the first row looks like so I can suggest a fix?

Comment: @Ram - Those are all valid names as long as there aren't leading/trailing spaces. I added `strip()` to elem_name in the Python (`elem_name.strip()`). Give that a try and let me know if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Ram - I also removed some debug code from the XSLT. Oops. :-)

Comment: everything seems to be good except a couple of small things, I just noticed in the first line i missed the ' encoding="UTF-8"? ' and the next one is the if run the script i am getting - x1,y2,x2,z2,R,c1,z1,y1. The order shoulde be - x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,c1,R. Is it possible to define the column order by indexing i mean instead of iterating to all columns? and the next one is it possible to sort the "id" ?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 may be that could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

First read all rows from CSV and sort them.

Later you can use variable `previous_id` to open and close `Roughness-Profile`/`surfaces` only when `id` in new row is different then in previous one.

I used `StringIO` to simulate csv file and `sys.stdout` to simulate xml file - so everybody can copy code and run it to see how it works

```
text ='''id,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,c1,R
a1,1.3,2.1,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.8,B,7.3
b2,1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,G,7.1
c1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,G,8.1
a1,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,S,8.2
b2,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,S,2.5
b2,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.3,7.4,8.2,G,3.1
c2,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,2.1,11.1,S,3.2
c1,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,A,1.5'''

from io import StringIO
import csv
import sys

#csvFile = r'C:\Users\Desktop\test XML\csvfile.csv'
#xmlFile = r'C:\Users\Desktop\test XML\myData.xml'

#csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
#xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')

csvData = csv.reader(StringIO(text))
xmlData = sys.stdout

# read all data to sort them
csvData = list(csvData)
tags = [item.replace(' ', '_') for item in csvData[0]] # headers
csvData = sorted(csvData[1:]) # sort data without headers

xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Roughness-Profiles xmlns="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">\n')

previous_id = None

for row in csvData:
    row_id = row[0]
    if row_id != previous_id:
        # close previous group - but only if it is not first group
        if previous_id is not None: 
            xmlData.write('</surfaces>\n</Roughness-Profile>\n')
        # open new group  
        xmlData.write('<Roughness-Profile>\n<id>{}</id>\n<surfaces>\n'.format(row_id))
        # remeber new group's id
        previous_id = row_id

    # surface
    xmlData.write('<surface>\n')
    for value, tag in zip(row[1:], tags[1:]): 
        xmlData.write('<{}>{}</{}>\n'.format(tag, value, tag))
    xmlData.write('</surface>\n')

# close last group
xmlData.write('</surfaces>\n</Roughness-Profile>\n')
xmlData.write('</Roughness-Profiles>\n')

#xmlData.close()
```

Version without `StringIO` and `sys.stdout`

```
import csv

csvFile = r'C:\Users\Desktop\test XML\csvfile.csv'
xmlFile = r'C:\Users\Desktop\test XML\myData.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')

# read all data to sort them
csvData = list(csvData)
tags = [item.replace(' ', '_') for item in csvData[0]] # headers
csvData = sorted(csvData[1:]) # sort data without headers

xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Roughness-Profiles xmlns="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">\n')

previous_id = None

for row in csvData:
    row_id = row[0]
    if row_id != previous_id:
        # close previous group - but only if it is not first group
        if previous_id is not None: 
            xmlData.write('</surfaces>\n</Roughness-Profile>\n')
        # open new group  
        xmlData.write('<Roughness-Profile>\n<id>{}</id>\n<surfaces>\n'.format(row_id))
        # remeber new group's id
        previous_id = row_id

    # surface
    xmlData.write('<surface>\n')
    for value, tag in zip(row[1:], tags[1:]): 
        xmlData.write('<{}>{}</{}>\n'.format(tag, value, tag))
    xmlData.write('</surface>\n')

# close last group
xmlData.write('</surfaces>\n</Roughness-Profile>\n')
xmlData.write('</Roughness-Profiles>\n')

xmlData.close()
```

Comment: Hi Furas, first i dont understand your stringIO and sys.stdout. explain it further it so that i can follow.  I ran de script without stringIO and sys.stdout lines. All the data is in desired order but missing de essential XML parsing in the output.

Comment: First: don't use StringIO and sys.stdout - use your files. I used StringIO and sys.stdout because I don't have your file and I had to similate it. And with StringIO and sys.stdout other users can run this code and see how it works - they don't need your file with data.

Comment: now I see I forgot closing '</Roughness-Profiles>'. I add it now. The rest seems the same. I used program [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) to compare your output with mine.

Comment: I added it before I wrote previous comment.

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept changes before so it didn't add it. But it is only one line `xmlData.write('</Roughness-Profiles>\n')` before `xmlData.close()`. Now change is in code.

Comment: @ Furas, thank you for changing the script.The output XML seems a bit different than the desired. i mean the all  lines in the output xml starts from the begining of the page. In the desired output there is indentation between the elements. I loaded the output xml in xml editor and it says the XML is valid. i will let you know on Monday whether the XML is accepting by the module or no?

Comment: XML parsers don't care for spaces and enters. You can have all data even in one line. Spaces are only for people. In code you can add as many spaces as you wish.

Comment: @Furaas- Thank you for the quick reply. i will let you know on Monday

Comment: @Furas- the xml output  through your script is good. I had no problems when loaded the xml in the module., Thank you once again.

Comment: @ furas,I have got another question, may be you are interested see the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851584/write-csv-file-using-python-with-the-help-of-a-csv-dictionary-nested-csv-dicti?noredirect=1#comment98366211_55851584)

Answer (score 0):

Because XML files are not text files but special text-based documents of structured data adhering to [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/), avoiding building the document by string concatenation.

Instead use appropriate DOM libraries available in virtually all modern programming languages including Python with its built-in `xml.etree` or more robust, third-party module, `lxml`. In fact, because your desired output involves grouping nodes by *id*, consider running XSLT, the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. The module, `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Below uses the `DictReader` of built-in `csv` module to build a nested id dictionary (all columns grouped under id keys). Then, XML is built by iterating through content of this dictionary to write data to element nodes.

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
import lxml.etree as ET

# BUILD NESTED ID DICTIONARY FROM CSV
with open("Input.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)      

    id_dct = OrderedDict({})
    for dct in reader:      
        if dct["id"] not in id_dct.keys():
            id_dct[dct["id"]] = [OrderedDict({k:v for k,v in dct.items() if k!= "id"})]
        else:
            id_dct[dct["id"]].append(OrderedDict({k:v for k,v in dct.items() if k!= "id"}))         

# INITIALIZING XML FILE WITH ROOT AND NAMESPACE
root = ET.Element('R-Profiles', nsmap={None: "http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1"})

# WRITING TO XML NODES
for k,v in id_dct.items():  
    rpNode = ET.SubElement(root, "R-Profile")
    ET.SubElement(rpNode, "id").text = str(k)
    surfacesNode = ET.SubElement(rpNode, "surfaces")

    for dct in v:
        surfaceNode = ET.SubElement(surfacesNode, "surface")
        for k,v in dct.items():         
            ET.SubElement(surfaceNode, k).text = str(v)

# OUTPUT XML CONTENT TO FILE
tree_out = ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")

with open('Output.xml','wb') as f:
    f.write(tree_out)
```

**Input.csv**

```
id,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,c1,R
a1,1.3,2.1,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.8,B,7.3
b2,1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,G,7.1
c1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,G,8.1
a1,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,S,8.2
b2,4.1,5.1,2.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,S,2.5
b2,3.6,4.5,5.1,6.3,7.4,8.2,G,3.1
c2,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,2.1,11.1,S,3.2
c1,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,A,1.5
```

**Output.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<R-Profiles xmlns="http://WKI/Roughness-Profiles/1">
  <R-Profile>
    <id>a1</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>1.3</x1>
        <y1>2.1</y1>
        <z1>3.6</z1>
        <x2>4.5</x2>
        <y2>5.1</y2>
        <z2>6.8</z2>
        <c1>B</c1>
        <R>7.3</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>2.2</x1>
        <y1>3.2</y1>
        <z1>4.2</z1>
        <x2>5.2</x2>
        <y2>6.2</y2>
        <z2>7.2</z2>
        <c1>S</c1>
        <R>8.2</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </R-Profile>
  <R-Profile>
    <id>b2</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>1.1</x1>
        <y1>2.1</y1>
        <z1>3.1</z1>
        <x2>4.1</x2>
        <y2>5.1</y2>
        <z2>6.1</z2>
        <c1>G</c1>
        <R>7.1</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>4.1</x1>
        <y1>5.1</y1>
        <z1>2.1</z1>
        <x2>7.1</x2>
        <y2>8.1</y2>
        <z2>9.1</z2>
        <c1>S</c1>
        <R>2.5</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>3.6</x1>
        <y1>4.5</y1>
        <z1>5.1</z1>
        <x2>6.3</x2>
        <y2>7.4</y2>
        <z2>8.2</z2>
        <c1>G</c1>
        <R>3.1</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </R-Profile>
  <R-Profile>
    <id>c1</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>2.1</x1>
        <y1>3.1</y1>
        <z1>4.1</z1>
        <x2>5.1</x2>
        <y2>2.1</y2>
        <z2>7.1</z2>
        <c1>G</c1>
        <R>8.1</R>
      </surface>
      <surface>
        <x1>1.5</x1>
        <y1>1.5</y1>
        <z1>1.5</z1>
        <x2>1.5</x2>
        <y2>1.5</y2>
        <z2>1.5</z2>
        <c1>A</c1>
        <R>1.5</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </R-Profile>
  <R-Profile>
    <id>c2</id>
    <surfaces>
      <surface>
        <x1>6.1</x1>
        <y1>7.1</y1>
        <z1>8.1</z1>
        <x2>9.1</x2>
        <y2>2.1</y2>
        <z2>11.1</z2>
        <c1>S</c1>
        <R>3.2</R>
      </surface>
    </surfaces>
  </R-Profile>
</R-Profiles>
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait, In the output file the "id" is not in the right place.

Comment: I misread your actual for desired output. See edit building a id dictionary and iterating through its content.

Comment: @Parafait, Thank you for the advise, Can you change the script so that i can understand much better.

Comment: @Ram, what more do you need? I include inline comments.

Comment: @Parafiat, thank you again. All main things are seems good except acouple of small things. the surface elements are not in order if run the script i am getting - x1,y2,x2,z2,R,c1,z1,y1.    The order shoulde  be - x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,c1,R. Is it possible to define the column order instead of iterating to all columns? and the next one is it possible to sort the "id" ?

Comment: Hmmm...as you can see with my output and after re-checking, I do not receive such an order. Are you sure the code you attempted mirrors this solution (without any modification) and CSV looks as you posted? I am using Python 3.7 which now order dictionaries. We may have to use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @Parfait- Thanks for your reaction, i am using Python 2.7 may be that could be the reason. yes order of the surface tags are in order. it could be fine that in the script i can give it for each column index or as you suggested to use  OrderedDict.

Comment: See edit using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Note the added `import` line from built-in `collections` module.

Comment: @Parfait- surprisingly nothing is changed still all the same i mean not in  proper order

Comment: @Parfait- i just noticed. its Python version problem, in Python3 its working good and in Python2 not.

Comment: Correct. As of Python 3.7, dictionaries now keep insertion order. Did `OrderedDict` not resolve in Python 2?

Comment: @Parfait- No, in Python 2,  i am not getting in correct order with OrderedDict.

Comment: Interesting! `DictReader` may behave differently in Python 2 then.

Comment: ,,I have got another question, may be you are interested see the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851584/write-csv-file-using-python-with-the-help-of-a-csv-dictionary-nested-csv-dicti?noredirect=1#comment98366211_55851584)