# Convert CSV File to XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am trying to set up a script to pull data from a CSV file to output to an XML file. I used the info from this link ([With PYTHON convert CSV file to XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503639/with-python-convert-csv-file-to-xml-file)) to create the script. It partially works, but I need some more guidance on getting the exact layout.

The layout I need is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ImportAcademicExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AcademicExtract>
        <StudentId>StudentID</StudentId>
        <LastName>LastName</LastName>
        <FirstName>FirstName</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>MiddleName</MiddleName>
        <SocialSecurityNumber>SocialSecurityNumber</SocialSecurityNumber>
        <BirthDate>BirthDate</BirthDate>
        <GradeLevel>GradeLevel</GradeLevel>
        <SpecialProgramIndicator>SpecialProgramIndicator</SpecialProgramIndicator>
        <CIPCode>CIPCode</CIPCode>
        <RegisteredHours>RegisteredHours</RegisteredHours>
        <PostalAddresses>
            <PostalAddress>
                <AddressLine1>Address</AddressLine1>
                <AddressLine2>Address2ndLn</AddressLine2>
                <City>City</City>
                <State>State</State>
                <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>Country</CountryCode>
            </PostalAddress>
        </PostalAddresses>
        <EmailAddresses>
            <EmailAddress>Email</EmailAddress>
        </EmailAddresses>
        <PhoneNumbers>
            <PhoneNumber>PhoneNumber</PhoneNumber>
        </PhoneNumbers>
        <AdmissionsTerm>
            <AdmissionTerm>
                <TermName>TermName</TermName>
                <AcademicYear>AcademicYear</AcademicYear>
                <AdmittedDate>AdmittedDate</AdmittedDate>
            </AdmissionTerm>
        </AdmissionsTerm>
        <EnrollmentTerms>
            <EnrollmentTerm>
                <TermName>TermNames</TermName>
                <AcademicYear>AcademicYears</AcademicYear>
                <CumulativeAttemptedHours>CumulativeAttemptedHours</CumulativeAttemptedHours>
                <CumulativeRegisteredHours>CumulativeRegisteredHours</CumulativeRegisteredHours>
                <CumulativeEarnedHours>CumulativeEarnedHours</CumulativeEarnedHours>
                <CumulativeGPA>CumulativeGPA</CumulativeGPA>
                <TermStartDate>TermStartDate</TermStartDate>
                <TermEndDate>TermEndDate</TermEndDate>
                <EnrollmentType>EnrollmentType</EnrollmentType>
                <EnrollmentStatus>EnrollmentStatus</EnrollmentStatus>
                <FirstTimeDegreeSeeking>FirstTimeDegreeSeeking</FirstTimeDegreeSeeking>
                <IntentToReturn>IntentToReturn</IntentToReturn>
                <WithdrawnDate>WithdrawnDate</WithdrawnDate>
                <ExtTermName>ExtTermName</ExtTermName>
                <AcademicYearStartDate>AcademicYearStartDate</AcademicYearStartDate>
                <AcademicYearEndDate>AcademicYearEndDate</AcademicYearEndDate>
                <ExtEnrollmentType>ExtEnrollmentType</ExtEnrollmentType>
                <DateOfDetermination>DateOfDetermination</DateOfDetermination>
                <LastDateOfAttendance>LastDateOfAttendance</LastDateOfAttendance>
                <SAPStatus>SAPStatus</SAPStatus>
            </EnrollmentTerm>
        </EnrollmentTerms>
        <AcademicPrograms>
            <AcademicProgram>
                <ProgramCredentialLevel>ProgramCredentialLevel</ProgramCredentialLevel>
                <ProgramName>ProgramName</ProgramName>
                <EdMajor1>EdMajor1</EdMajor1>
                <SiteName>SiteName</SiteName>
                <EffectiveStartDate>EffectiveStartDate</EffectiveStartDate>
                <EffectiveEndDate>EffectiveEndDate</EffectiveEndDate>
                <GraduationDate>GraduationDate</GraduationDate>
                <AnticipatedGraduationDate>AnticipatedGraduationDate</AnticipatedGraduationDate>
                <ProgramLengthInWeeks>ProgramLengthInWeeks</ProgramLengthInWeeks>
                <ProgramLengthInMonths>ProgramLengthInMonths</ProgramLengthInMonths>
                <ProgramLengthInYears>ProgramLengthInYears</ProgramLengthInYears>
                <AcademicYearBeginDate>AcademicYearBeginDate2</AcademicYearBeginDate>
                <AcademicYearEndDate>AcademicYearEndDate2</AcademicYearEndDate>
                <WeeksInProgramAcademicYear>WeeksInProgramAcademicYear</WeeksInProgramAcademicYear>
            </AcademicProgram>
        </AcademicPrograms>
    </AcademicExtract>
```

I am using the following script:

```
import itertools
import csv
import os

csvFile = r'J:\JFAFiles\JFA-BR.csv'
xmlFile = r'J:\JFAFiles\XML-BR.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' + "\n" +'<ImportAcademicExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' + "\n" )

rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
        xmlData.write('        '+'<AcademicExtract>' +"\n")
        for i in range (len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('                ' +'<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                      + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

        xmlData.write('        '+'</AcademicExtract>' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</ImportAcademicExtract>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

When I run the script, I cannot figure out how to bring in the inserted areas as seen (like Postal Addresses area, email addresses, phone numbers, admissions terms, etc.) Everything stays in line.

Output from running script is below. The underscores are where text is input from the file that I removed because of sensitive information. The text comes over correctly, I just do not know how to get those other areas inserted more.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ImportAcademicExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <AcademicExtract>
                <StudentID>____</StudentID>
                <LastName>____</LastName>
                <FirstName>____</FirstName>
                <MiddleName>____</MiddleName>
                <SocialSecurityNumber>____</SocialSecurityNumber>
                <BirthDate>____</BirthDate>
                <GradeLevel>____</GradeLevel>
                <SpecialProgramIndicator>____</SpecialProgramIndicator>
                <CIPCode>____</CIPCode>
                <RegisteredHours>____</RegisteredHours>
                <Address>____</Address>
                <Address2ndLn>____</Address2ndLn>
                <City>____</City>
                <State>____</State>
                <PostalCode>____</PostalCode>
                <Country>____</Country>
                <Email>____</Email>
                <PhoneNumber>____</PhoneNumber>
                <TermName>____</TermName>
                <AcademicYear>____</AcademicYear>
                <AdmittedDate>____</AdmittedDate>
                <TermName2>____</TermName2>
                <AcademicYear2>____</AcademicYear2>
                <CumulativeAttemptedHours>____</CumulativeAttemptedHours>
                <CumulativeRegisteredHours>____</CumulativeRegisteredHours>
                <CumulativeEarnedHours>____</CumulativeEarnedHours>
                <CumulativeGPA>____</CumulativeGPA>
                <TermStartDate>____</TermStartDate>
                <TermEndDate>____</TermEndDate>
                <EnrollmentType>____</EnrollmentType>
                <EnrollmentStatus>____</EnrollmentStatus>
                <FirstTimeDegreeSeeking>____</FirstTimeDegreeSeeking>
                <IntentToReturn>____</IntentToReturn>
                <WithdrawnDate>____</WithdrawnDate>
                <ExtTermName>____</ExtTermName>
                <AcademicYearStartDate>____</AcademicYearStartDate>
                <AcademicYearEndDate>____</AcademicYearEndDate>
                <ExtEnrollmentType>____</ExtEnrollmentType>
                <DateOfDetermination>____</DateOfDetermination>
                <LastDateOfAttendance>____</LastDateOfAttendance>
                <SAPStatus>____</SAPStatus>
                <ProgramCredentialLevel>____</ProgramCredentialLevel>
                <ProgramName>____</ProgramName>
                <EdMajor1>____</EdMajor1>
                <SiteName>____</SiteName>
                <EffectiveStartDate>____</EffectiveStartDate>
                <EffectiveEndDate>____</EffectiveEndDate>
                <GraduationDateDate>____</GraduationDateDate>
                <AnticipatedGraduationDate>____</AnticipatedGraduationDate>
                <ProgramLengthInWeeks>____</ProgramLengthInWeeks>
                <ProgramLengthInMonths>____</ProgramLengthInMonths>
                <ProgramLengthInYears>____</ProgramLengthInYears>
                <AcademicYearBeginDate2>____</AcademicYearBeginDate2>
                <AcademicYearEndDate2>____</AcademicYearEndDate2>
                <WeeksInProgramAcademicYear>____</WeeksInProgramAcademicYear>
        </AcademicExtract>
</ImportAcademicExtract>
```

I tried adding this to the scripting, but it did not work:

```
rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
        xmlData.write('        '+'<AcademicExtract>' +"\n")
        for i in range (len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('                ' +'<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                      + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

    if rowNum == 11:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
        xmlData.write('                        '+'<PostalAddresses>' +"\n"+'                                '+'<PostalAddress>' +"\n")
        for i in range (len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('                ' +'<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                      + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
```

Any help is appreciated on how to edit the coding to get the layout correct.

Comment: The XML you have posted is nested while csv file is flat - gow do you bridge this gap?

Comment: I was able to map the XML schema in Excel to export to XML correctly in the CSV files, but I have 7 of the same style student databases that I would have to do this for every time I need to upload updates. So trying to find a solution to that. Even if it isn't with Python coding. Just Python gave me the closest results to my export.

Answer (score 1):

I think pandas dataframes are easier for this, you can use the following script, it's likely not very efficient.

all you need to do is change the xml_map to define the output you want.

save this python script in a file called csv2xml.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd, argparse, os

xml_map = {"AcademicExtract" : ["StudentID", "LastName", "FirstName", "MiddleName", "SocialSecurityNumber",
                        "BirthDate", "GradeLevel", "SpecialProgramIndicator", "CIPCode", "RegisteredHours",
                        {"PostalAddresses" : { "PostalAddress" : [ "Address", "Address2ndLn", "City", "State", "PostalCode", "Country" ] } },
                        {"EmailAddresses" : [ "Email" ] },
                        {"PhoneNumbers" : ["PhoneNumber"] },
                        {"AdmissionsTerm" : { "AdmissionTerm" : [ "TermName", "AcademicYear", "AdmittedDate" ] } },
                        {"EnrollmentTerms" : { "EnrollmentTerm" : [ "TermName2", "AcademicYear2", "CumulativeAttemptedHours",
                                                "CumulativeRegisteredHours", "CumulativeEarnedHours", "CumulativeGPA",
                                                "TermStartDate", "TermEndDate", "EnrollmentType", "EnrollmentStatus",
                                                "FirstTimeDegreeSeeking", "IntentToReturn", "WithdrawnDate", "ExtTermName",
                                                "AcademicYearStartDate", "AcademicYearEndDate", "ExtEnrollmentType", "DateOfDetermination",
                                                "LastDateOfAttendance", "SAPStatus" ] } },
                        {"AcademicPrograms" : { "AcademicProgram" : [ "ProgramCredentialLevel", "ProgramName", "EdMajor1", "SiteName",
                                                "EffectiveStartDate", "EffectiveEndDate", "GraduationDateDate", "AnticipatedGraduationDate",
                                                "ProgramLengthInWeeks", "ProgramLengthInMonths", "ProgramLengthInYears", "AcademicYearBeginDate2",
                                                "AcademicYearEndDate2", "WeeksInProgramAcademicYear" ] } } ] }

# this name map is used to rename terms in the XML output
# the map is of the format "oldname":"newname", "oldname2":"newname2"
name_map = {"TermName2" : "TermName", "AcademicYear2" : "AcademicYear"}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='convert csv 2 xml')
parser.add_argument('input_file', help='filename to convert')
parser.add_argument('output_file', help='output filename')

args = parser.parse_args()
if not os.path.isfile(args.input_file): raise ValueError('File does not exist: ' + args.input_file)
outfile = open(args.output_file,"w")

def printXML(data, xmlm, level):
    if isinstance(xmlm,dict):
        for k in xmlm:
            node_name = name_map.get(k,k)
            print(" "*level*4,f"<{node_name}>",file=outfile)
            printXML(data,xmlm[k],level+1)
            print(" "*level*4,f"</{node_name}>",file=outfile)
    elif isinstance(xmlm,list):
        for i in xmlm: printXML(data,i,level+1)
    elif data[xmlm].strip():
        node_name = name_map.get(xmlm,xmlm)
        print(" "*level*4,f"<{node_name}>",end="",file=outfile)
        print(data[xmlm],end="",file=outfile)
        print(f"</{node_name}>",file=outfile)

df = pd.read_csv(args.input_file,dtype=str,keep_default_na=False,header=0)

print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>',file=outfile)
print('<ImportAcademicExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">',file=outfile)
df.apply(lambda x: printXML(x, xml_map, 1), axis=1)
print("</ImportAcademicExtract>",file=outfile)
outfile.close()
```

for the xml_map variable I extracted the list of elements from your second example output as this looks like the actual column names in the file.

the column names in the xml_map arrays, anything between square brackets [ ... ] must match the column names in your input file

in this example the input file is:

```
StudentID,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,SocialSecurityNumber,BirthDate,GradeLevel,SpecialProgramIndicator,CIPCode,RegisteredHours,Address,Address2ndLn,City,State,PostalCode,Country,Email,PhoneNumber,TermName,AcademicYear,AdmittedDate,TermName2,AcademicYear2,CumulativeAttemptedHours,CumulativeRegisteredHours,CumulativeEarnedHours,CumulativeGPA,TermStartDate,TermEndDate,EnrollmentType,EnrollmentStatus,FirstTimeDegreeSeeking,IntentToReturn,WithdrawnDate,ExtTermName,AcademicYearStartDate,AcademicYearEndDate,ExtEnrollmentType,DateOfDetermination,LastDateOfAttendance,SAPStatus,ProgramCredentialLevel,ProgramName,EdMajor1,SiteName,EffectiveStartDate,EffectiveEndDate,GraduationDateDate,AnticipatedGraduationDate,ProgramLengthInWeeks,ProgramLengthInMonths,ProgramLengthInYears,AcademicYearBeginDate2,AcademicYearEndDate2,WeeksInProgramAcademicYear
1,Brown,Adam,,12345678,01/01/1970,Masters,SPI1,CIP1,20,this is line 1,this is line 2,NY,NY,PC123,USA,adam@example.com,213415441,Summer,2020,Date1,Autmn,2021,Attempted Hours1,Registered Hours1,Earned Hours 1,GPA1,Date1,Date2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,Baker,Andrew,,43219952,02/01/1970,PHD,SPI2,CIP2,30,this is line 1,this is line 2,NY,NY,PC234,USA,andrew@example.com,132141541,Summer,2020,Date2,Autmn,2021,Attempted Hours2,Registered Hours2,Earned Hours 2,GPA2,Date1,Date2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Note: that first line in your CSV file must contain column names

I am assuming you are using powershell and that you have python installed.  run the script as follow:

```
python csv2xml.py "J:\JFAFiles\JFA-BR.csv" "J:\JFAFiles\XML-BR.xml"
```

Note: use quotes around file names as windows allows spaces in filenames and paths

if you get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' then you will need to install pandas module

```
pip.exe install pandas
```

if you get a key error when you run it like:

```
KeyError: 'studentID'
```

Note: the column names are case sensitive

then you can run the following python code to check the actual column names in the dataframes

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_csv("J:\JFAFiles\JFA-BR.csv",dtype=str,keep_default_na=False,header=0)
print(df.columns)
```

The result of running the script on the sample input above is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ImportAcademicExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <AcademicExtract>
             <StudentID>1</StudentID>
             <LastName>Brown</LastName>
             <FirstName>Adam</FirstName>
             <MiddleName></MiddleName>
             <SocialSecurityNumber>12345678</SocialSecurityNumber>
             <BirthDate>01/01/1970</BirthDate>
             <GradeLevel>Masters</GradeLevel>
             <SpecialProgramIndicator>SPI1</SpecialProgramIndicator>
             <CIPCode>CIP1</CIPCode>
             <RegisteredHours>20</RegisteredHours>
             <PostalAddresses>
                 <PostalAddress>
                         <Address>this is line 1</Address>
                         <Address2ndLn>this is line 2</Address2ndLn>
                         <City>NY</City>
                         <State>NY</State>
                         <PostalCode>PC123</PostalCode>
                         <Country>USA</Country>
                 </PostalAddress>
             </PostalAddresses>
             <EmailAddresses>
                     <Email>adam@example.com</Email>
             </EmailAddresses>
             <PhoneNumbers>
                     <PhoneNumber>213415441</PhoneNumber>
             </PhoneNumbers>
             <AdmissionsTerm>
                 <AdmissionTerm>
                         <TermName>Summer</TermName>
                         <AcademicYear>2020</AcademicYear>
                         <AdmittedDate>Date1</AdmittedDate>
                 </AdmissionTerm>
             </AdmissionsTerm>
             <EnrollmentTerms>
                 <EnrollmentTerm>
                         <TermName2>Autmn</TermName2>
                         <AcademicYear2>2021</AcademicYear2>
                         <CumulativeAttemptedHours>Attempted Hours1</CumulativeAttemptedHours>
                         <CumulativeRegisteredHours>Registered Hours1</CumulativeRegisteredHours>
                         <CumulativeEarnedHours>Earned Hours 1</CumulativeEarnedHours>
                         <CumulativeGPA>GPA1</CumulativeGPA>
                         <TermStartDate>Date1</TermStartDate>
                         <TermEndDate>Date2</TermEndDate>
                         <EnrollmentType></EnrollmentType>
                         <EnrollmentStatus></EnrollmentStatus>
                         <FirstTimeDegreeSeeking></FirstTimeDegreeSeeking>
                         <IntentToReturn></IntentToReturn>
                         <WithdrawnDate></WithdrawnDate>
                         <ExtTermName></ExtTermName>
                         <AcademicYearStartDate></AcademicYearStartDate>
                         <AcademicYearEndDate></AcademicYearEndDate>
                         <ExtEnrollmentType></ExtEnrollmentType>
                         <DateOfDetermination></DateOfDetermination>
                         <LastDateOfAttendance></LastDateOfAttendance>
                         <SAPStatus></SAPStatus>
                 </EnrollmentTerm>
             </EnrollmentTerms>
             <AcademicPrograms>
                 <AcademicProgram>
                         <ProgramCredentialLevel></ProgramCredentialLevel>
                         <ProgramName></ProgramName>
                         <EdMajor1></EdMajor1>
                         <SiteName></SiteName>
                         <EffectiveStartDate></EffectiveStartDate>
                         <EffectiveEndDate></EffectiveEndDate>
                         <GraduationDateDate></GraduationDateDate>
                         <AnticipatedGraduationDate></AnticipatedGraduationDate>
                         <ProgramLengthInWeeks></ProgramLengthInWeeks>
                         <ProgramLengthInMonths></ProgramLengthInMonths>
                         <ProgramLengthInYears></ProgramLengthInYears>
                         <AcademicYearBeginDate2></AcademicYearBeginDate2>
                         <AcademicYearEndDate2></AcademicYearEndDate2>
                         <WeeksInProgramAcademicYear></WeeksInProgramAcademicYear>
                 </AcademicProgram>
             </AcademicPrograms>
     </AcademicExtract>
     <AcademicExtract>
             <StudentID>2</StudentID>
             <LastName>Baker</LastName>
             <FirstName>Andrew</FirstName>
             <MiddleName></MiddleName>
             <SocialSecurityNumber>43219952</SocialSecurityNumber>
             <BirthDate>02/01/1970</BirthDate>
             <GradeLevel>PHD</GradeLevel>
             <SpecialProgramIndicator>SPI2</SpecialProgramIndicator>
             <CIPCode>CIP2</CIPCode>
             <RegisteredHours>30</RegisteredHours>
             <PostalAddresses>
                 <PostalAddress>
                         <Address>this is line 1</Address>
                         <Address2ndLn>this is line 2</Address2ndLn>
                         <City>NY</City>
                         <State>NY</State>
                         <PostalCode>PC234</PostalCode>
                         <Country>USA</Country>
                 </PostalAddress>
             </PostalAddresses>
             <EmailAddresses>
                     <Email>andrew@example.com</Email>
             </EmailAddresses>
             <PhoneNumbers>
                     <PhoneNumber>132141541</PhoneNumber>
             </PhoneNumbers>
             <AdmissionsTerm>
                 <AdmissionTerm>
                         <TermName>Summer</TermName>
                         <AcademicYear>2020</AcademicYear>
                         <AdmittedDate>Date2</AdmittedDate>
                 </AdmissionTerm>
             </AdmissionsTerm>
             <EnrollmentTerms>
                 <EnrollmentTerm>
                         <TermName2>Autmn</TermName2>
                         <AcademicYear2>2021</AcademicYear2>
                         <CumulativeAttemptedHours>Attempted Hours2</CumulativeAttemptedHours>
                         <CumulativeRegisteredHours>Registered Hours2</CumulativeRegisteredHours>
                         <CumulativeEarnedHours>Earned Hours 2</CumulativeEarnedHours>
                         <CumulativeGPA>GPA2</CumulativeGPA>
                         <TermStartDate>Date1</TermStartDate>
                         <TermEndDate>Date2</TermEndDate>
                         <EnrollmentType></EnrollmentType>
                         <EnrollmentStatus></EnrollmentStatus>
                         <FirstTimeDegreeSeeking></FirstTimeDegreeSeeking>
                         <IntentToReturn></IntentToReturn>
                         <WithdrawnDate></WithdrawnDate>
                         <ExtTermName></ExtTermName>
                         <AcademicYearStartDate></AcademicYearStartDate>
                         <AcademicYearEndDate></AcademicYearEndDate>
                         <ExtEnrollmentType></ExtEnrollmentType>
                         <DateOfDetermination></DateOfDetermination>
                         <LastDateOfAttendance></LastDateOfAttendance>
                         <SAPStatus></SAPStatus>
                 </EnrollmentTerm>
             </EnrollmentTerms>
             <AcademicPrograms>
                 <AcademicProgram>
                         <ProgramCredentialLevel></ProgramCredentialLevel>
                         <ProgramName></ProgramName>
                         <EdMajor1></EdMajor1>
                         <SiteName></SiteName>
                         <EffectiveStartDate></EffectiveStartDate>
                         <EffectiveEndDate></EffectiveEndDate>
                         <GraduationDateDate></GraduationDateDate>
                         <AnticipatedGraduationDate></AnticipatedGraduationDate>
                         <ProgramLengthInWeeks></ProgramLengthInWeeks>
                         <ProgramLengthInMonths></ProgramLengthInMonths>
                         <ProgramLengthInYears></ProgramLengthInYears>
                         <AcademicYearBeginDate2></AcademicYearBeginDate2>
                         <AcademicYearEndDate2></AcademicYearEndDate2>
                         <WeeksInProgramAcademicYear></WeeksInProgramAcademicYear>
                 </AcademicProgram>
             </AcademicPrograms>
     </AcademicExtract>
</ImportAcademicExtract>
```

Comment: What software would this be built in? Also, where do you put the path for the data import from the CSV file and the export for the finished XML? Sorry for all the questions, but fairly new to SQL, Powershell, Python coding and such. But learning on the fly is the best way. I have gotten all my processes to about 98% automated and this is the last piece for complete automation instead of manually mapping and getting me the one XML file with all the data. Been accomplishing a lot through SQL and Powershell, so may have more questions.

Comment: @daf0555 it is a python script, i've updated my answer (and script) with more details on how it works and how you can use it.

Comment: That worked really well. Thanks for providing this! One more question, is there a way to change the name for the tags within python (instead of pulling the column name in certain areas)? And if so, would it be better to change them through python when running the scripting or would it be better to just have the CSV file to export using the names I need for the tags? I just don't want the scripting to get confused in the cases of having the same name for two different columns (i.e. Term Name under Admissions Term nesting and also having Term Name under Enrollments Term nesting).

Comment: it is better to do this in python as pandas does not allow multiple columns with the same name and will automatically rename the second instance of the column "Term Name" to "Term Name.1" and third instance to "Term name.2" etc...  i'll update the answer to include a name map that you can use to rename certain columns as needed

Comment: i've updated it, all you need to do is add the name changes you need to the name_map dictionary

Comment: One more thing I am missing that was caught when it tried to upload. The tags are still there when the CSV data is NULL. I see some ways to remove the tags when NULL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652470/clean-xml-remove-line-if-any-empty-tags), but don't know where to place it. and I don't want to mess up this coding that is working. Essentially, if there is no data in AddressLine2, then there would just be AddressLine1 then City Tags below it. But needed for all NULL values within to just ignore the tags when data is NULL. I think my upload will work after that.

Comment: What does a null like look like in the output file.  Is it <addressline2>NULL</addressline2> or <addressline2></addressline2> without the word NULL?

Comment: It actually just removes the tags if there is nothing in there. So if there is NULL in the column it will remove the tag.

How it comes out when mapped from Excel and exported. AddressLine2 was NULL in this case. So it just did not place it in. 
  <PostalAddresses>
   <PostalAddress>
    <AddressLine1>Line 1</AddressLine1>
    <City>City</City>
    <State>State</State>
    <PostalCode>Zip Code</PostalCode>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
   </PostalAddress>
  </PostalAddresses>

Essentially, it would need to just remove the tags whenever any column is NULL.

Comment: I changed the script so it would not output the blank entries.  the change is in the printXML function,  the `else:` changes to `elif data[xmlm].strip():`

Comment: I appreciate all your help on this. The scripting worked and exported the CSV file to the XML and uploaded correctly.